# Android Eclipse how to display a XML file if there is no internet connection exists

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, network-programming, show

Hi my app to display a XML file if there is no internet connection exists. But the app always destroys itself!

I use this code here!

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    String status = netInfo.getState().toString();
    if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.no);
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    }

public void end (View view){
    finish();
    System.exit(0);}

   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onResume();
        return;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="###"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0.0.006"
     android:installLocation="auto">

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> 
        <activity
            android:name="###.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
              <activity android:name=".NoConnectionActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I display the xml?

I have already "setContentView(R.layout.no);"

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting while trying the above code? Post crash log here so we can have a better idea about what's going on.

Comment: I get no crash log ! if i have it! If I had to I would have written it! can you tell me how I can do it differently?

Comment: I asked for crash log because there is no reason for app it kill itself without any reason.I am answering your question comment on my answer if you need further help.

Comment: And you can definitely do it differently like merging both activity_main.xml and no.xml into one. When there is an internet connectivity show views of activity_main.xml hide views of no.xml and when there is no internet connectivity show views of no.xml hide views of activity_main.xml. But before you do that you have make sure application is executing the line you thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

Bascially, create a new activity with the `No connection` template. Then in your main activity, add the following code:

```
if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
else 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoConnectionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any log so that we could try to help you ?

Comment: No its chash only. Application could not be started.`import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NoConnectionActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.no);

 }

}`

Comment: Ops i forget sry i try it

Comment: get not yet. I'm doing what the "manifest" wrong? `<activity
            android:name=".NoConnectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: You can simply do that: `<activity android:name=".NoConnectionActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />`

Comment: Add a `Log.e(">>>", "1");` after each line and increment the counter. Let's see how fart it goes.

Comment: You can't have the same error if you have added the `Log.e`. Please post your whole manifest (Edit your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    String status = null;
    if(netInfo!=null){
        status = netInfo.getState().toString();
    }else{
        status = "";
    }           
    if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.no);
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }}catch(Exception e){ setContentView(R.layout.no);
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

Comment: When there is an internet connectivity does it work?

Comment: Yes i have no internet conection and then crash the app if i have internet conection then work the app

Comment: I meant to say what happens when you have internet connection? Does your app work? Because we have to take care of two situation here. When we have internet connection and when we don't have internet connection.

Comment: If i have a Internet connection then work this app Perfect. If i dont have the connection then crash it!

Comment: Sometimes getActiveNetworkInfo() can return null which might cause you nullpointerexception that's why i putted if(netInfo!=null). Since it's still not working then the case might be bit different.

Comment: We have to make sure the system execute ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    String status = null;
    if(netInfo!=null){
        status = netInfo.getState().toString();
    }else{
        status = "";
    } this code successfully. Try putting all the above code into try catch.

Comment: Edited my answer for your convenience.

Comment: `try {if (netInfo != null) {status = netInfo.getState().toString();} else {status ="";setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}if (netInfo != null) {status =netInfo.getState().toString();setContentView(R.layout.no);Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} else {status = "";setContentView(R.layout.no);Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}} catch (Exception ex) {Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}`

Comment: and i Try it so `catch (Exception ex) {
      setContentView(R.layout.no);
      Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }`

Comment: I am running out of ideas about what might be the problem since your app gets no crash.who is calling end method? Remove return from onResume it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Now is Removed return from onResume but nothing. i have test it @ 2.2 2.3 and 4.1.1 and 4.4 :c

Comment: Still no change? and who is calling public void end (View view){
    finish();
    System.exit(0);} method?

Comment: `public void end` is a Button to close the app

Comment: matter, then the app is not so nice.

Comment: If you still don't get any closer to the solution i think what you have to do is line by line debugging.